# Momentjs adding utcoffset without changing datetime

Tags: javascript, moment-timezone

at the moment I am trying to add a utc offset to a date string such as "2023-01-17T06:00:00Z"
the desired result would be 2023-01-17T06:00:00+11:00
so far everything I do adds the +11:00 offset but changes the actual time as well for example
"2023-01-17T06:00:00Z" >> "2023-01-17T17:00:00+11:00"
instead I would want
"2023-01-17T06:00:00Z" >> "2023-01-17T06:00:00+11:00"

here is the code I've tried but hasn't worked.

moment(2023-01-17T06:00:00Z).tz(timeZone, true)

this still ends up adding the offset to the original datetime
i was wondering if anyone knew how to do this?
im using moment-timezone btw.

Comment: Those aren't the same times though? If you know you want a time 11 hours earlier why are you initializing it in UTC?

Comment: because i know its timezone but i get it in YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ format the api i pull from doesnt have timezones

Comment: You mean it has a `Z`? that would indicate that the times are UTC so the shift is expected and accurate.

Comment: oh so would it be better if i added a +00:00 to the end and then tried to manipulate it that way

Comment: +00 is the same as Z. I think you need to post examples of the API data and how you expect to use it to clarify why you are wanting to shift it 11 hours

Comment: the api returns data with datetime as 2023-01-17T08:55:00, which will be in the sites local time such as australia/sydney i want to add the utcoffset to this time because this is actually 2023-01-17T08:55:00+11:00, let me know if this still doesn't make sense.

Comment: @pilchard I've found a work around thanks for your help I didn't know the z means utc necessarily thanks aha.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm glad it helped. If you know the offset you can just put it on the end of the ISO string. `moment(2023-01-17T08:55:00+11:00)`